# google chrome - plugin click to play not working in youtube

Tags: google-chrome

chrome version: 35.0.1916.114 m

I enabled the **click to play** option in chrome settings; it works fine everywhere except in youtube; in youtube the flash contents load as usual and it starts playing the video automatically;

what is wrong? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Youtube is using flash, and not HTML5? It seems that the latter is the case, which is why its not working. If you enable flash output in the settings in youtube, I suspect that it will start working.

Comment: any solution or extension maybe for stopping youtube videos from auto load or auto play?

Comment: I don't use Google Chrome myself, so I can't tell you how to do it in there, but I use Opera 12.17 and I disabled that any flash plugin can start automatically. Instead I get a placeholder that I need to click before the content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled Click to play via Settings > Show advanced settings > Content Settings > Plug-ins > Click to play, then you probably set YouTube as an exception.

Go to `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#plugins` (paste into your address bar) and you might see something like `https://[*.]www.youtube.com:443`. To remove it, rollover it and click the cross on the right.